Unable to understand how I'm supposed to gas optimize this cuz it keeps saying the gas fees is too high and likely to fail. How do I fix this?
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "./Errors.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/interfaces/IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/libraries/VRFV2PlusClient.sol";
import { ReentrancyGuard } from "solady/src/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract CoinFlip is VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus, ReentrancyGuard {
    // Chainlink VRF parameters
    IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus internal immutable COORDINATOR;
    bytes32 internal immutable KEY_HASH;
    uint256 private immutable SUBSCRIPTION_ID;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant CALLBACK_GAS_LIMIT = 1e5;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    IERC20 public accelCoin;
    uint256 constant MIN_BET = 1 ; // 1 AccelCoin (assuming 18 decimals)
    uint256 constant MAX_BET = 100 ; // Maximum bet limit for AccelCoin
    uint256 private contractBalance;

    struct PlayerByAddress {
        address playerAddress;
        uint256 betChoice;
        uint256 betAmount;
        bool betOngoing;
        uint256 balance;
    }

    struct Temp {
        address playerAddress;
        uint256 id;
    }

    mapping(address => PlayerByAddress) public playersByAddress;
    mapping(uint256 => Temp) public temps;

    event NewIdRequest(address indexed player, uint256 requestId);
    event Withdrawal(address indexed player, uint256 amount);
    event BetResult(address indexed player, bool victory, uint256 amountWon); // Added event

    constructor(
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        bytes32 _keyHash,
        uint256 _subscriptionId,
        address _accelCoinAddress
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus(_vrfCoordinator) {
        COORDINATOR = IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus(_vrfCoordinator);
        KEY_HASH = _keyHash;
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID = _subscriptionId;
        accelCoin = IERC20(_accelCoinAddress);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Allows a player to bet on heads or tails
     * @param _betChoice 0 for heads, 1 for tails
     * @param _amount Amount of AccelCoin being bet
     */
    function bet(uint256 _betChoice, uint256 _amount) public nonReentrant {
        if (_amount < MIN_BET) revert CoinFlip__InsufficientAmount();
        if (_amount > MAX_BET) revert CoinFlip__AmountTooBig();

        address player = msg.sender;
        PlayerByAddress memory _player = playersByAddress[player];

        if (_player.betOngoing) revert CoinFlip__BetAlreadyOngoing();

        _player.playerAddress = player;
        _player.betChoice = _betChoice;
        _player.betOngoing = true;
        _player.betAmount = _amount;

        playersByAddress[player] = _player;

        // Transfer AccelCoin from the player to the contract
        bool success = accelCoin.transferFrom(player, address(this), _amount);
        require(success, "Transfer failed");

        contractBalance += _amount;

        uint256 requestId = requestRandomWords();
        temps[requestId].playerAddress = player;
        temps[requestId].id = requestId;

        emit NewIdRequest(player, requestId);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Allows players to withdraw their balance
     */
    function withdrawPlayerBalance() public nonReentrant {
        address player = msg.sender;
        if (playersByAddress[player].betOngoing) revert CoinFlip__BetOngoing();
        if (playersByAddress[player].balance == 0) revert CoinFlip__NoFundsToWithdraw();

        uint256 amount = playersByAddress[player].balance;
        delete playersByAddress[player];

        // Transfer AccelCoin from the contract to the player
        bool success = accelCoin.transfer(player, amount);
        if (!success) revert CoinFlip__WithdrawFailed();

        emit Withdrawal(player, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Assumes the subscription is funded sufficiently.
     */
    function requestRandomWords() private returns (uint256) {
        return
            COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
                VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({
                    keyHash: KEY_HASH,
                    subId: SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
                    requestConfirmations: REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
                    callbackGasLimit: CALLBACK_GAS_LIMIT,
                    numWords: NUM_WORDS,
                    extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({ nativePayment: false }))
                })
            );
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, uint256[] calldata _randomWords) internal override {
        uint256 randomResult = _randomWords[0] % 2;
        checkResult(randomResult, _requestId);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Check if the player won the bet and update the player's balance accordingly
     * @param _randomResult The random number generated by Chainlink VRF
     * @param _requestId The requestId of the VRF call
     * @return win True if the player won the bet, false otherwise
     */
    function checkResult(uint256 _randomResult, uint256 _requestId) private returns (bool) {
        address player = temps[_requestId].playerAddress;
        bool win = false;
        uint256 amountWon = 0;

        PlayerByAddress memory _player = playersByAddress[player];

        if (_player.betChoice == _randomResult) {
            win = true;
            amountWon = _player.betAmount * 2;
            _player.balance += amountWon;
            contractBalance -= amountWon;
        }

        _player.betAmount = 0;
        _player.betOngoing = false;
        playersByAddress[player] = _player;

        emit BetResult(player, win, amountWon); // Emitting the BetResult event

        delete temps[_requestId];
        return win;
    }
}

Unable to optimize this contract. I've tried various methods to lower the gas fees but I'm just not able to. Tried some tools too like etherscan estimator, but no help there either. I've passed all the values correctly as needed in the code.

Have you created a subscription on https://vrf.chain.link and added your contract as a consumer to that subscription?

yep i have. i also made a frontend on a hardhat project when remix didnt work but i cant make it work there either. is there some flaw in the logic of the contract or is it just not gas optimized is what im wondering now..

Gas optimization is not a problem in this. Please let me know the network on which you’ve deployed this contract, along with the constructor params that you’re passing. I’ll try to debug that on my end.
